# Get the last x day from a string in android (e.g. 20140310 , last 2 day , return 20140308)

Tags: android, date, calendar

How can serve a string as a date and reduce 2 day, 
after that return the result as an string ?

Just similar to the title example? Thanks

This is some related code but it seems deduct from current date and not output as a string like e.g. 20140308, thanks

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); 
calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -2);
```

Comment: Hope you have get him idea from the following link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21473696/android-display-date-from-one-week-to-another-like-thursday-to-thursday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to parse your String as a Date based on the pattern of your choice - in your case it is `yyyyMMdd`.

Then you can perform operations on that date which you want to re-format as a String based on your pattern.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd"); //Set SimpleDateFormat per your pattern
    String dateStr = "20140310"; // Your Date as String
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(sdf.parse(dateStr)); // Set the date to Calendar instance
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -2); // Perform Operation

    System.out.println(sdf.format(cal.getTime())); //20140308
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to parse the date from the `String` into a `Date` something like this:

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").parse("YOUR DATE STRING");
```

Then set the time from that date, to the `Calendar` instance:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(date);
```

At this point, calendar's date is the one you had in your string, and you can deduct 2 days or whatever you want from that date and not *today*

```
c.add(Calendar.DATE, -2);
```