# How to get Current Week details as well as Quarter Details in android?

Tags: android, date, calendar

I am having current date from which I want to calculate current week as well as Quarter of the Current month in android. 
How can I achieve this?
I am using Calendar to get current date. 
Please help me for this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: see the answer on this post,this is my post check this, hope u get him idea from it and if it is worked then let me know.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21473696/android-display-date-from-one-week-to-another-like-thursday-to-thursday/21676492#21676492

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of a DateSelection Class i put together. I created an Activity then i had this as a sub class in my Activity.

```
private class DateSelection{

    //---------------------------------------------------
    // Initial Date
    private Calendar currentDate    = null;

    // Two GregorianCalendar Objects to Return 
    private GregorianCalendar beginDate         = null;
    private GregorianCalendar endDate           = null;

    private int buttonId = -1;
    private int month = -1;
    private int year = -1;

    //---------------------------------------------------
    // Constructor
    public DateSelection(int buttonId){

        // Initialize the buttonId to the passed in value
        this.buttonId = buttonId;

        // Initialize the new GregorianCalendar Objects
        currentDate = new GregorianCalendar();

        // Set the Current Month
        month   = currentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);

        // Set the Current Year
        year    = currentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        beginDate   = new GregorianCalendar();
        endDate     = new GregorianCalendar();

        // Set the Current Date Selection 
        setCurrentDateSelection();
    }

    // Constructor : Creates a new Date Selection Object with Two Dates
    public DateSelection(GregorianCalendar beginDate, GregorianCalendar endDate){

        // Set the Being and End Dates for this object
        this.beginDate  = beginDate;
        this.endDate    = endDate;
    }

    // Sets the Current Date based on the Button Used
    public void setCurrentDateSelection(){
        // Switch on the buttons id
        switch(buttonId){
            // Current Month
            case 0: 
                getCurrentMonth();
                break;

            // Current Quarter
            case 1:
                getCurrentQuarter();
                break;

            // Current Year
            case 2: 
                getCurrentYear();
                break;
            case 3: 
                getPriorMonth();
                break;

            case 4: 
                getPriorQuarter();
                break;

            case 5: 
                getPriorYear();
                break;
            case 6:
                getMonthToDate();
                break;
            case 7:
                getQuarterToDate();
                break;
            case 8:
                getYearToDate();
                break;

            // Default Case
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    // Returns the Current Month Range as a Date Selection Object
    public DateSelection getCurrentMonth(){

        // Determine the First and Last Day of the Current Month
        int firstOfMonth    = currentDate.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int lastOfMonth     = currentDate.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Set the Year, Month and Date for the beginDate
        beginDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        beginDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        beginDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, firstOfMonth);

        // Set the Year, Month and Date for the endDate
        endDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        endDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        endDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, lastOfMonth);

        // Return the new DateSelection Object
        return new DateSelection(beginDate, endDate);

    }

    // Returns the Current Quarter Range as a DateSelection Object
    public DateSelection getCurrentQuarter(){

        // Determine the Quarter Begin and Quarter End Months
        int quarterBeginMonth = (((month - 1) / 3) * 3);
        int quarterEndMonth = quarterBeginMonth + 2;

        // Set the Month and Year for the Current Quarter
        beginDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, quarterBeginMonth);
        beginDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);

        // Determine First Day of the Quarter Begin Month
        int firstDayOfBeginMonth = beginDate.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        // Set the Day for the Begin Date of the Current Quarter
        beginDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, firstDayOfBeginMonth);

        // Set the Current Quarter Ending Month and Year
        endDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, quarterEndMonth);
        endDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);

        // Determine the Last Day of the Quarter End Month
        int lastDayOfEndMonth = endDate.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        // Set the endDate Date of Month
        endDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, lastDayOfEndMonth);

        // Return the new DateSelection Object
        return new DateSelection(beginDate, endDate);

    }

    // Returns the Current Year Range as a DateSelection Object
    public DateSelection getCurrentYear(){

        // Determine the int values of the first and last months of the year
        int firstMonth = currentDate.getActualMinimum(Calendar.MONTH);
        int lastMonth = currentDate.getActualMaximum(Calendar.MONTH);

        // Set the Month for beginDate
        beginDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, firstMonth);

        // Determine the int value for the first Day of the Year
        int firstDayOfYear = beginDate.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        // Set the Day for Begin Date to the first Day of the year
        beginDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, firstDayOfYear);
        // Set the Month for the endDate to the Last month of the year
        endDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, lastMonth);

        // Determine the last day of the Year from the given month
        int lastDayOfYear = endDate.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Set the Day of the endDate to the Last day of the year
        endDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, lastDayOfYear);

        // Return the new DateSelection Object
        return new DateSelection(beginDate, endDate);
    }

    // Returns the Prior Month as a DateSelection Object
    public DateSelection getPriorMonth(){

        // Decrement the Month by 1 to get the prior month
        month -= 1;

        // Allow for underflow to the previous year
        if(month < 0)
        {   
            month = 11;
            year--;
        }

        // Determine the int value for the first month of the year
        int firstOfMonth    = currentDate.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Set the Year, Month, and Day
        beginDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        beginDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        beginDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, firstOfMonth);

        // Determine the int value for the last month of the year
        int lastOfMonth     = currentDate.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Set the Year, Month, and Day
        endDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        endDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        endDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, lastOfMonth);

        // Return the new DateSelection Object
        return new DateSelection(beginDate, endDate);
    }

    // Returns the Prior Quarter as a DateSelection Object
    public DateSelection getPriorQuarter(){

        // Determine the int values for the Begin and End Quarter Months
        int quarterBeginMonth = (((month - 1) / 3) * 3);
        int quarterEndMonth = quarterBeginMonth + 2;

        // Subtract 3 from the 
        quarterBeginMonth   -= 3;
        quarterEndMonth     -= 3;

        // Allow for underflow for the previous year
        if(quarterBeginMonth < 0)
        {   
            quarterBeginMonth += 12;
            quarterEndMonth += 12;

            year --;    
        }

        // Set the Begin Date's Month and Year
        beginDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, quarterBeginMonth);
        beginDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);

        // Get First Day of Quarter's Begin Month
        int firstDayOfBeginMonth = beginDate.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        beginDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, firstDayOfBeginMonth);

        // Set the End Date's Month and Year
        endDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, quarterEndMonth);
        endDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);

        // Determine the Last Day of the Quarter's End Month
        int lastDayOfEndMonth = endDate.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        // Set the End Day for the End Month
        endDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, lastDayOfEndMonth);

        // Return the new DateSelection Object
        return new DateSelection(beginDate, endDate);
    }

    // Returns the Prior Year Range as a DateSelection Object
    public DateSelection getPriorYear(){

        // Decrement the Year by 1 to get the Prior Year
        year -= 1;

        // Determine the int values for the Current years first and last months
        int firstMonth = currentDate.getActualMinimum(Calendar.MONTH);
        int lastMonth = currentDate.getActualMaximum(Calendar.MONTH);

        // Set the Begin date's Year and Month
        beginDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        beginDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, firstMonth);

        // Determine the first day of the first month of the previous year
        int firstDayOfYear = beginDate.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        // Set the beginDate to the first day of the previous year
        beginDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, firstDayOfYear);

        // Set the End date's Year and Month
        endDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        endDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, lastMonth);

        // Determine the last day of the last month of the previous year
        int lastDayOfYear = endDate.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        // Set the endDate to the last day of the previous year
        endDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, lastDayOfYear);

        // Return the new DateSelection Object
        return new DateSelection(beginDate, endDate);
    }       

    // Returns the Month to Date as a DateSelection Object
    public DateSelection getMonthToDate(){

        // Determine the int value for the first day of the Month
        int firstOfMonth = currentDate.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Set the Year, Month, and Day for the Begin Date
        beginDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        beginDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        beginDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, firstOfMonth);

        // Set the endDate to the Current Date
        endDate = (GregorianCalendar) currentDate;

        // Return the new DateSelection Object
        return new DateSelection(beginDate, endDate);
    }

    // Returns the Quarter to Date as a DateSelection Object
    public DateSelection getQuarterToDate(){

        // Determine the int value for the current Quarter's beginning month
        int quarterBeginMonth = (((month - 1) / 3) * 3);

        // Set the Month and Year for the beginMonth
        beginDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, quarterBeginMonth);
        beginDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);

        // Determine the First Day of Quarter's Begin Month
        int firstDayOfBeginMonth = beginDate.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        // Set the day of the beginDate to the first day of the Quarter's Month
        beginDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, firstDayOfBeginMonth);

        // Set the end Date to the Current Date
        endDate = (GregorianCalendar) currentDate;

        // Return the new DateSelection Object
        return new DateSelection(beginDate, endDate);
    }

    // Returns the Year to Date as a DateSelection Object
    public DateSelection getYearToDate(){

        // Determine the first Month of the Year
        int firstMonth = currentDate.getActualMinimum(Calendar.MONTH);

        beginDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, firstMonth);

        int firstDayOfYear = beginDate.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        beginDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, firstDayOfYear);

        // Set the end Date to the Current Date
        endDate = (GregorianCalendar) currentDate;

        // Return the new DateSelection Object
        return new DateSelection(beginDate, endDate);
    }

}
```

Then to get the Dates I create a class Variable of a `DateSelection Object` and then used buttons and id's to control which date returns.

For example for the current year i created a button added a click listener like this:

Class variable: `DateSelection m_dateSelection = null;`
And an int id `private static final int BUTTON_CURRENT_MONTH = 0;`

```
OnClickListener CurrentMonthListener = new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        m_dateSelection = new DateSelection(BUTTON_CURRENT_MONTH);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Current Month is from "+ calendarToNumberString( m_dateSelection.beginDate) + " to "+ calendarToNumberString(m_dateSelection.endDate), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

};
```

And then in my sub class you can see how i use a switch statement to control the ouput.

Good Luck

Comment: And you can copy the code from get CurrentMonth, use GregorianCalendar to find the current date, then add 7 or find current date, get first day of week, last day off week, etc.