# Year not exceed year 2000 in Datepicker in android

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-datepicker

I have a DatePicker in my activity. I want to set the year max limit to 2000, so that datepicker dont show years which is exceed year 2000. how can i implement this.currently i have used this code to set current date :

```
     dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());
```

current work img :

[image]

I want look this :

[image]

this is my code :

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int cyear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int cmonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int cday = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        // start changes...
        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                mDateSetListener, cyear, cmonth, cday);
        dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());
        return dialog;
        // end changes...
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this piece of code

`protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    Date d=new Date();
    Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0);
    d.setTime(cal.getTimeInMillis());
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int cyear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int cmonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int cday = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        // start changes...
        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                mDateSetListener, cyear, cmonth, cday);
        dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(d.getTime());
        return dialog;
        // end changes...
    }
    return null;
}`

Answer (score 1):

You set current date that's why you are seeing 2014.

You can set bounds of your DatePicker by:

```
setMinDate(long minDate)
setMaxDate(long maxDate)
```

How you are going to set the values is explained by MH. in the topic below in details:

[Set Limit on the DatePickerDialog in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18272306/set-limit-on-the-datepickerdialog-in-android/18353944#18353944)