# How to set the limit on date in Date picker dialog

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I want to put the limit on date so that user can not pick date more then that, for example if today is 1 January then User should not be able to select more then 7 dates , I mean he can not select 9 January. I also want him not to select the month and year. So I am putting a limit to set his task in one week.

what I have done so far is showing the date picker fragment and setting current date in it. the code in my main activity goes like this:

```
etSelectDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DialogFragment datePickerFragment = new DatePickerFragment() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
                        Log.d("Date Change", "onDateSet");
                        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                        c.set(year, month, day);
                        DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
                        etSelectDate.setText(df.format(c.getTime()));
                        //nextField.requestFocus(); //moves the focus to something else after dialog is closed

                    }
                };
                datePickerFragment.show(MainActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");

            }
        });
```

and date picker fragment class goes like this :

```
 public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
            //blah
        }
    }
```

till then its is working fine , but I do not know how to put the limit on date and rest of the months and year should be non Select able . I have seen many link such as like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18272306/set-limit-on-the-datepickerdialog-in-android) , but I do not understand How can I do that and also there is nothing helpful on android site.

> So please help me , How can I put limit of seven days only

**Update**

Through your replies I know how to set the max date in calender , so As I want to set the max date 7 days ahead of current date , I am still not getting it. the method I read so far is :

```
pickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());
```

It is setting the current date as maximum, but How can I add 7 days ahead in it since it is Date object ? please help

Comment: you can go through the complete thread here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18272306/set-limit-on-the-datepickerdialog-in-android

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/45671497/6478047

Comment: I am using date picker. Its works fine. But when opening the picker I need to show the default year as ten years back. But i the user scroll needs to show up to the current year. Does it has any method to show the default date in the widget and while scrolling up or down it needs to show the year as usual.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have the `setMinDate(long)` and `setMaxDate(long)` methods at your disposal. Both of these will work on API level 11 and above. Since you are using a `DatePickerDialog`, you need to first get the underlying DatePicker by calling the `getDatePicker()` method.

```
dpdialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(minDate);  
dpdialog.getDatePicker().setmaxDate(maxDate);
```

Source :[Set Limit on the DatePickerDialog in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18272306/set-limit-on-the-datepickerdialog-in-android/18353944#18353944)

You can calculate the minDate by using,

```
Date today = new Date();
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(today);
c.add( Calendar.MONTH, -6 ) // Subtract 6 months
long minDate = c.getTime().getTime() // Twice!
```

**Updated :**

Replace the below line

```
return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
```

with

```
 // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
    DatePickerDialog pickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    pickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(maxDate);
    pickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(minDate);
    return pickerDialog;
```

Comment: I have seen this thread earlier but How can I implement in my case

Comment: @stacyqueen Updated my answer, have a look

Comment: so how can I put limit of seven days in Max date ? and min date would be cureent date for sure ?

Comment: Your solution helped me a lot , but there is one problem in it

Comment: @stacyqueen What is the problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81597/discussion-between-stacy-queen-and-kartheek).

Comment: After setting the `setMaxDate` of datePicker the `setMaxDate` is always highlighted and selected, here is the [image](http://imgur.com/5WPjzcu)

Answer (score 11):

In some cases, when you set maximum date with a date without hours and minutes, you won't be able to select the maximum date you set.
For instance

```
 Calendar maxDate = Calendar.getInstance();
            maxDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day + 5);
            maxDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
            maxDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);

 datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(maxDate.getTimeInMillis());
```

With the code block above, you can not click to your maxDate.

But if you add hours and minutes to like;

```
            maxDate.set(Calendar.HOUR, 23);
            maxDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
```

to your maxDate, your last date will be clickable

Answer (score 1):

by using

`setMinDate` and `setMaxDate`

[MinDate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#setMinDate%28long%29)

[MaxDate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#setMaxDate%28long%29)

Comment: can you please elaborate it more. where I can use this and in which format

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
DatePickerDialog dpDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, pDateSetListener, pYear, pMonth, pDay);
DatePicker datePicker = dpDialog.getDatePicker();

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();//get the current day
datePicker.setMaxDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());//set the current day as the max date or put yore date in miliseconds.
datePicker.setMinDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());//set the current day as the min date or put your date in mili seconds format
return dpDialog;
```